# How do I remove objects from an NSMutableArray matching an NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an array like this:

```
    {
    id = 8281;
    name = “John”;
    title = “Title One“;
     },
    {
    id = 8729;
    name = “Bob”;
    title = “Title Two“;
    },
    {
    id = 8499;
    name = “Dave”;
    title = “Title Three“;
    }
```

I want to remove the array containing a specific ID.

As an example, let's say I have:

```
NSNumber *removeThis =  '8281' ;
```

And my array above is named "stories".

I have tried:

```
[stories removeObject:removeThis];
```

but that does not work.

I have also tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id != %@", removeThis];
NSArray *results = [stories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

But the data is never removed from the array.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this:

```
NSNumber *removeThis =  '8281';
```

...is even valid Objective-C. Use `@(number)` to make an `NSNumber` literal, like:

```
NSNumber *removeThis =  @(8281);
```

From there, it should work exactly as you typed it:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id != %@", removeThis];
NSArray *results = [stories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Yup, that should work. However, that will create a new array `results` rather than modifying the array `stories`. If you want to remove the objects from the `stories` array "in place" you'd use `[stories filterUsingPredicate: predicate]`.

Comment: Thanks - these suggestions helped - especially passing the number as a string.  Where I got hung up was that the array I was updating was already in use, and it was not updating after I filtered it.  I eventually was able to get it updated by doing this:
@synchronized(stories)
            {
                NSArray *results = [stories filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
                stories = [results mutableCopy];
            }